# I saw an Ai drop the Aegis on another Ai's Circle of Power. How did it do it?

Tags: dota, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

And can a human player do it too?

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuy6T.png%5D)

[image]

Comment: The AI probably cheats and/or can do stuff that you're not allowed to.